# getting video dimensions

Tags: posts, videos

when attaching videos (eg. .flv) to a post - is it possible to query its dimensions?
the problem is - i've got videos in 4:3 and 16:9 format and i need to get this information.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Do you upload the videos yourself or do you embed them from other sites? Which sites then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[php-flvinfo](http://code.google.com/p/php-flvinfo/) and [php-mp4info](http://code.google.com/p/php-mp4info/) are php classes for reading flv and mp4 metadata. you could read it on the fly, or it may be possible to hook a save to get this info in the db somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I retrieve video (or any non-image) meta data.

```
// assuming you have an attachment ID
$meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment->ID );

// See what meta data is available
print_r( $meta );

// always check for the property's existence before trying to display it
if ( ! empty( $meta['width'] ) )
 echo $meta['width'];
```

You can echo any meta that is returned with print. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Please add proper description to why your code would work, and how your code work. Just dropping code as an answer is not allowed

Comment: The code I have shared was already commented inline, but I edited my response to include some additional information. Why the downvote though? :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need a plugin to do this. It would need to parse the video and save the meta information.

I'd recommend taking a look at this library for starters: http://code.google.com/p/flv4php/

As for implementing this as a WordPress plugin, you would need to write a function and hook it to the wp_generate_attachment_metadata filter. The code will basically look something like this:

```
function my_attachment_metadata($meta, $attachment_id) {
  $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
  $mime = get_post_mime_type( $attachment );
  $file = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );
  // use the $mime value to determine if you need to scan the file (video/x-flv)
  // use the $file for scanning for any meta data
  // store the meta data in $meta['whatever'] for each piece of info
  return $meta;
}
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','my_attachment_metadata',10,2);
```

Any meta data you add to $meta and return there will be stored along with the attachment post. You can then later retrieve it, without having to reparse the file or anything, with wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id ).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use videos to test. My quick guess would be to try [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) function.

Comment: WordPress will only save attachment metadata for images (EXIF & sizes). Looks like the need of a plugin to add support for video..